# Error: Call to a member function getTranslation() on null on paragraph deletion

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, paragraph

I want to delete the paragraphs from a field in a node; if the field has paragraphs in there or not. The below code throws the following error:

Error: Call to a member function getTranslation() on null in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->hasTranslationChanges()

```
    // delete all map_legend and map_item paragraphs before
    if (!empty($d8_node->field_map_legends->getValue())) {
        foreach ($d8_node->field_map_legends->getValue() as $paragraph) {
            if ($paragraph["target_id"]) {
                $previous_paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph["target_id"]);

                if ($previous_paragraph) {
                    $previous_paragraph->delete();
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

When I comment out the $previous_paragraph->delete() it doesn't throw the error, but the paragraphs aren't deleted.

I've tried try/catch around the delete. I've tried if isset on $previous_paragraph and on the field_map_legends itself. I've tried everything I can think of.

I apologize if this is a duplicate somewhere else. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that deleting a Paragraph does not remove references to that Paragraph. In this case field_map_legends on this node is still referencing the deleted paragraph through the target_id, even though the Paragraph with that ID no longer exists.

The safest way to do this is to remove the reference from the node instead of directly deleting the Paragraph (though you can do both together if preferred).

```
  // delete all map_legend and map_item paragraphs before
  if ($d8_node->hasField('field_map_legends')) {

    // Optional. Delete the Paragraph entities.
/*
    foreach ($d8_node->field_map_legends->getValue() as $paragraph) {
      if ($paragraph["target_id"]) {
        $previous_paragraph = Paragraph::load($paragraph["target_id"]);

        if ($previous_paragraph) {
          $previous_paragraph->delete();
        }
      }
    }
*/

    // Remove all of the Paragraph references from this field.
    $d8_node->set('field_map_legends', []);
    // Save our changes to the node.
    $d8_node->save();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I'm just worried about orphaned paragraphs. I ended up doing doing the same thing you suggested but the reason I posted was I wasn't sure if that was the correct way of doing it.

Thank you for your help!